# Is the function $f(x) = \cos{x} \sin{x}$ a rational function?

Tags: calculus

is the function $$f(x) = \cos{x} \sin{x}$$ a rational function?

Comment: No. But it can be written as $f(x)=R(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ where $R(x,y)=xy$ is a rational function.

Comment: @Ian Thank you  :) Now I can understand it well

Answer (score 9):

A real-valued rational function of a single real variable can be written as a ratio of two polynomials in that variable. If not identically zero, such a function necessarily has a finite number of zeroes (these are limited to the zeroes of the polynomial in the numerator).

It follows immediately that your function can't be a rational function since it has an infinite number of real zeroes and is not identically zero.

Comment: $x\mapsto 0$ is a rational function.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Correct, if pedantic. Still, OP's function is clearly not the rational function $x\mapsto 0$. I have amended my answer for this obvious exception.

Answer (score 6):

Consider a rationnal function $R(x)$, then the limit $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} R(x)$$ is equal to a constant or to infinity. However $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \sin(x)\cos(x)$$ doesn't exist. Hence $x \mapsto \sin(x)\cos(x)$ can't be a rationnal function.

Comment: What about $\sin{1/x}$ we should take the limit for $x\rightarrow 0$ or $x\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: To $0$ if you want a similar argument.

Comment: So it is not a general rule?

Comment: What about $f(x) = e^x$?

Comment: @Navaro It is not a rule, in the sense that there are functions that converge to a constant or infinity as $x \to \infty$. That is just true of every rational function. For $e^x$, do you know that exponentials grow faster than any polynomial?

Comment: @Julian: yes I know

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = \cos x \sin x$$

can be written as $$f(x) = \frac{\sin 2x}{2}$$

since $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin x \cos x$

Hence, $f(x)$ cannot be rational, since $\sin t$ is not rational.

$\sin t$ is defined as a convergent series (according to its Taylor expansion)

Comment: This is almost circular reasoning. How is it obvious that $\sin t$ is not a rational function while it is not obvious that $\cos t\sin t$ is not a rational function?

Comment: I guess that's fair - if you can recognise $sin(x)$ isn't rational, then you can arguably recognise $cos(x)sin(x)$ isn't rational. However, seeing that $sin(x)$ is more "elementary" than the latter which was why I wrote it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a rational function.

*However,* if we define $y=cosx$ and $z=sinx$, then

$f^*(z,y)=zy$ *is* a rational function of $z$ and $y$.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Why $f^*(z,y)$ is a rational function?

Comment: Any polynomial is a rational function, since it is the quotient of a polynomial and 1 and the constant function 1 is a polynomial. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function

Comment: thank you, but what about for example $f(x) = e^x$ I think it is not rational, right?

Comment: No of course it isn't; it's not the quotient of polynomials

Comment: On the other hand, if we define $y=e^x$ and $f^*(y)=y(=e^x)$, then $f^*$ is a rational function (of y), if that makes any sense.

Comment: Thank you very much William this is the most helpful, the others assume (stupidly) that I know what a rational function is.